# Angular 2 safari doesnt appear to work correctly

Tags: angularjs, safari, typescript, angular

I have a problem. I'm on angular2 beta 17 and my code works properly in chrome and firefox but in Safari my component doesnt appear. I get the data from firebase and put it in a component. Actually it is a chat, I get the messages from firebase. Getting the data is fast, but the messages doesnt appear until I manually put the focus in the input field. I have tried manual change detection but didn't work.

Any ideas what can be the problem or how can I solve this?

Best Regards

Comment: can you post some code or replicate in a plunkr?

Comment: This issue seems to be ngFor related. I'm experiencing this too on safari, everything is fine on chrome and firefox. However i can't replicate it in plunkr so the debug process is gonna be so difficult.